# composite key in web2py

Tags: python, web2py, composite-key

I have a table defined in web2py

```
db.define_table(
'pairing',
Field('user',writable=True,readable=True),
Field('uid', writable=True , readable=True)
)
```

This table needs to have user and uid combination being unique. I have looked through the web2py documentation , but there isn't direct way to define composite key . 
How do we define composite way in web2py

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. By default, web2py automatically creates an auto-incrementing `id` field to serve as the primary key for each table, and that is the recommended approach whenever possible. If you are dealing with a legacy database with composite primary keys and cannot change the schema, you can specify a `primarykey` attribute, though with some limitations (as explained [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/6#Legacy-databases-and-keyed-tables)):

```
db.define_table('pairing', 
    Field('user', writable=True, readable=True), 
    Field('uid', writable=True, readable=True),
    primarykey=['user', 'uid'])
```

Perhaps instead you don't really need a true composite primary key, but you just need some way to ensure only unique pairs of user/uid values are inserted in the table. In that case, you can do so by specifying a properly constructed `IS_NOT_IN_DB` validator for one of the two fields:

```
db.define_table('pairing',
    Field('user', writable=True, readable=True),
    Field('uid', writable=True, readable=True))

db.pairing.uid.requires=IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(db.pairing.user==request.vars.user),
    'pairing.uid')
```

That will make sure `uid` is unique among the set of records where `user` matches the new value of `user` being inserted (so the combination of `user` and `uid` must be unique). Note, validators (such as IS_NOT_IN_DB) are only applied when values are being inserted via a `SQLFORM` or using the `.validate_and_insert()` method, so the above won't work for arbitrary inserts into the table but is primarily intended for user input submissions.

You can also use SQL to set a multi-column unique constraint on the table (which you can do directly in the database or via the web2py `.executesql()` method). Even with such a constraint, though, you would still want to do some input validation within your application to avoid errors from the database.

Comment: I have a table where I would like to do validation on two other fields. sh_code and sh_organization. I tried with your suggested code but record is still inserted. Any suggestions

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code. The above approach works with any two fields.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using a computed field to create/simulate a composite key. Taking the example from the above question, one can define the junction table as follows:

```
from md5 import md5
db.define_table( 'pairing',
                 Field('user', writable=True, readable=True),
                 Field('uid', writable=True, readable=True),
                 Field( 'user_uid_md5', 
                        length=32,
                        unique=True,
                        writable=False,
                        readable=False,
                        compute=lambda row: md5("{0}:{1}".format(row.user,row.uid)).hexdigest()))
```

The `user_uid_md5` field is automatically computed on insert and updates. The value of this field is the [md5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash of a string obtained from the two fields `user` and `uid`. This field is also marked as `unique`. So the database enforces uniqueness here and this works around the limitation pointed out by [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685846/1062948). This should also work to emulate composite keys with more than two fields. If you see any holes in this approach, please let me know.

Edit: Slight update to the way the md5 hash is computed to account for the case pointed out by [Chen Levy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110488/chen-levy) in a comment below.

Comment: This is actually a clever approach; however, I've decided to use the built in input validation to keep things standard.

Comment: This is _almost_ correct. You should also take into account the cases where the different combinations of `user` and `uid` result in the same string, e.g. `user=1` and `uid=21` vs. `user=12` and `uid=1`. In this case both will yield the `md5('121')` and will conflict with each other.

Comment: @ChenLevy, good point. To account for this possibility I have updated the solution slightly. Let me know if you see any issue with it.

Comment: Actually I think it would make more sense to simply use integer: `lambda row: ((row.user << 16) | (row.uid))`. I might be wrong but there's always a chance you get same md5 for 2 different pairs of user/uid. That's assuming each ID field is smaller than 16.