# how to set a multi-column unique in web2py

Tags: mysql, web2py, requires

In order to make many to many relation ship I make a middle table to combine two tables ,the tables like this:

```
db.define_table('problem',
                Field('task_id','reference task'),
                Field('title','string',unique=True,length=255))
db.define_table('task',
                Field('title','string',unique=True,length=255),
                Field('course_id','reference courses'))

db.define_table('belong',
                Field('task_id','reference task'),
                Field('problem_id','reference problem')
                )
db.belong.task_id.requires=IS_IN_DB(db,'task.id','%(title)s')
db.belong.problem_id.requires=IS_IN_DB(db,'problem.id','%(title)s')
```

I use SQLFORM to insert into `belong` table.I want there are no duplicate task and problem. suppose there is a record like `(1,task1,problem1)`already exist in `belong` table,then if I choose task1 in SQLFORM,how to make the problem_id dropdown list not to show problem1. I have found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683604/composite-key-in-web2py)
and do some test like the following in `db.py`:

```
test1:  

db.belong.problem_id.requires=IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(db.belong.task_id==request.vars.task_id),'belong.problem_id').

test2:

db.belong.problem_id.requires=IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(db.belong.task_id==request.vars.task_id),'problem.id','%(title)s').
```

test3:

```
def my_form_processing(form):
    a = form.vars.task_id
    b=form.vars.problem_id
    query=(db.belong.task_id==a)&(db.belong.problem_id==b)
    if query :
        form.errors.a= 'the record has existed'

def assignproblem():
    form=SQLFORM(db.belong)
    if form.process(onvalidation=my_form_processing).accepted:
        response.flash='form accepted'
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash='form has errors'
    else:
        response.flash='please fill out the form'
    return dict(form=form)
```

but it still not been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the choices in the problem_id dropdown to change dynamically based on the task_id selection, then you will need to use JavaScript (and likely make an Ajax request to populate the dropdown). For possible solutions, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146260/best-practice-for-populating-dropdown-based-on-other-dropdown-selection-in-web2p/8152910#8152910).

As for your tests above, test1 should do the proper validation, but only after the form has been submitted (i.e., the form will allow any combination of task_id and problem_id to be selected but will then report an error if a duplicate combination has been submitted).

test3 does not work as is because the `query` object just specifies the database query without actually doing a select from the database. Instead, you must call the `.select()` method, or more simply, the `.count()` method:

```
if db((db.belong.task_id == a) & (db.belong.problem_id == b)).count():
    form.errors.a= 'the record has existed'
```

Comment: Many thanks，after modification，test3 works,I think it's better to make an Ajax request to populate the dropdown.